# Using Same xs element under different sequences in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I am trying to create an XSD file for an xml that uses the same XS string under different sequences, but due to being in multiple namespaces an error pops out when trying to validate on eclipse.
I cant change the XML so im trying to adapt the XSD to it.....

```
.....
<xs:element name ="expample1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="urn.Name" xlmns:urn="urn:twister:std:csd:operator"/>
        </sx:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name ="expample2">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="urn.Name" xlmns:urn="urn:twister:std:csd:operatorprofile"/>
        </sx:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

any advise?
thanks in advance

Comment: *...an error pops out...*:  Always specify such errors verbatim in your question.

Comment: When seeking debugging help, include a [mcve] illustrating the problem.  In this case, it should include the smallest XSD and XML that exhibit the problem.

Comment: Thanks for advising.... The error is the following: 
Error resolving component "urn:Name". It was detected that "urn:Name" is in namespace "urn:twister.std.csd.operatorprofile" but cmponents from this namespace are ot referenceable from shcema document......

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add a verbatim copy (use copy-paste -- don't re-type) of your error message, and add a [mcve] to get the best help for your problem.  By doing this, you enable those seeking to help you to fully analyze the problem, and often verify a suggested solution, thereby providing ideal help rather than just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You write

```
ref="urn.Name" xlmns:urn="urn:twister:std:csd:operatorprofile"/>
```

There seem to be at least two things wrong here:

(a) it should be `xmlns:urn` not `xlmns:urn`

(b) it should be `urn:Name` not `urn.Name`.

The error message mentions `urn:Name` so perhaps you got it right somewhere else in your code, or perhaps you're not showing us the code that actually failed, in which case we haven't any chance of being able to help you.